# Swagger Bearer always return 501 with good token in ASP Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bearer-token

In my web API I'm using swagger. Everything worked fine, but since 5 hours there is no way to execute a request to my API from swagger, it always returns me

```
{
"access-control-allow-origin": "*",
"date": "Wed, 21 Jun 2017 12:20:52 GMT",
"www-authenticate": **"Bearer error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The 
 token is expired\""**,
"x-sourcefiles": "=?UTF-8?B?pcdXNlcnNcdmR1XGRvY3VtZW50c1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTdcUHJvamVjdHNcV2ViQXBwbGljY         
XRpb24xXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxhcGlcVGVlcGVl?=",
"server": "Kestrel",
"x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
"content-length": "0",
"content-type": null
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs config

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        //services.AddAuthorization(options => options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("IdentityApplication").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());                       

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme() { In = "header", Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field", Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey" });
        });
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });
    }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        ConfigureAuth(app);

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSwagger();           
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });


    }
```

I'm using a token passed in header "Authorization" to every api request.

Every requets are working if I execute them in POSTMAN or from an application.

But with swagger it returns me the 401 error : Unauthorized.

I checked if the token is in the header of the request, it is.

Here is an exemple of the request header of a get request from swagger :

```
Accept:text/plain
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4  
Authorization:Bearer MyToken
```

Comment: I found a problem, the response date of swagger is 14:00:00 and I send the request a 16:00:00 so my token is expired. I don't know why there is a difference of 2 hours between the request and the response

Comment: Maybe is because one of them is being returned in UTC?